# Should explicit instantiation of templates be used if I want to limit what types a class template can accept?

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

I have a templated class, and I want to only allow certain types to be used. I believe one way to do this is to use explicit instantiation at the end of the source file -- I believe this will cause linker errors if the developer tried to instantiate a type that is not one of the explicitly instantiated types.

However, when I searched on SO, e.g., in the 2 links below, I did not see any mentioning of using explicit instantiation, so I am questioning if explicit instantiation shoudl be used for this.

Could someone advise?

[restrict a template function, to only allow certain types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267324/restrict-a-template-function-to-only-allow-certain-types)

[Restricting templates to only certain classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669528/restricting-templates-to-only-certain-classes)

Answer (score 2):

C++ has evolved over the last decade, and what you described was a common hack that is no longer necessary. This (and several alternative approaches) was used with older C++ standards by using a combination of two kinds of sub-optimal practices: defining the actual template in a standalone translation unit and explicitly instantiating the template methods (including its constructor) in that translation unit, and by relying on the fact that, otherwise, [templates can only be effectively implemented in a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/). This effectively achieves that goal by producing a cryptic link failure.

Fortunately, that hack is not needed in modern C++ any more. As I mentioned, C++ has evolved to the point where something like that can be specified cleanly, explicitly, and in a crystal clear way using C++20 constraints:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
    requires std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, char>
struct my_template {};

my_template<int> a;      // OK
my_template<char> b;     // OK
my_template<char *> c;   // ERROR
```

Your actual template can be defined and implemented normally, in a header file, and the constraint clearly imposes a restriction that your template be instantiated only with specific types.